# How can I move a point along a line in 3D space to reach a target dot product with a fixed reference point?

Tags: vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, 3d

Suppose a point in 3D space, Q.

For any other point x in that space, Let Q(x) be the unit vector pointing from x towards Q.

I also have a line L in 3D space, and a point on this line P.  L = {P + k*w}, for any scalar k and a given unit vector w that points from P along L.

I also have some vector v of unit length.

Finally, I have a target value T.

I am interested in computing P' = P + q*w (which is to say, I'd like solve for q), that brings Q(P') * v as close as possible to T, where * is dot product.

Intuitively, since Q() and v are unit length and the dot product is thus cosine, I'm trying to move P to P' so that the angle formed by P -> Q and v matches a target value, or at least gets as close as possible.

This is for a real life problem that I am writing a program for, and the program needs to be efficient.  As such, kudos for avoiding expensive calculations (sin, cosine, sqrt, etc.)

**Edit - Example**
  Suppose:

- P = (0,0,0)
- w = (-1, 0, 0)
- v = (0, 1, 0)
- Q = (0, 1, 0)
- T = 1/2

One solution is q = sqrt(3).

P' = P + qw = (-sqrt(3), 0, 0)
Q(P') = (sqrt(3)/2, 1/2, 0)
Q(P') * v = 0*sqrt(3)/2 + 1/2 * 1 = 1/2 = T

Comment: If $(P+kw-Q)\cdot v=t$, can't you just do $k=\frac{t+Q\cdot v-P\cdot v}{w\cdot v}$?

Comment: First just a technicality, it should be (Q - (P+kw)).  Second, unfortunately that is not unit length, so you have to multiply the right hand side by ||Q - P - kw|| first.  When I tried to brute force solve this I got a really messy quadratic that I don't understand, that does not always solve, or worse sometimes seems to solve but then yields -t instead of t.  I was hoping for a more intuitive answer.

Comment: I was not sure what $T$ was. Is it between $[-1,1]$? If it is not, then apparently you can only get $1$ or $-1$ as the closest value.

Comment: T is equal to some cos(Theta), so it is between [-1, 1].  The nuance that saves me in the statement above is that I'm using Q(P'), which has the normalization by ||Q - P - kw|| baked into it.  I was trying to be concise, but perhaps glossed over too much.  I've added an example to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might just want to solve a quadratic equation then.

$$\frac{(Q-P-kW)\cdot v}{||Q-P-kW||}=t$$

Let $Q-P=(a_1,a_2,a_3), W=(b_1,b_2,b_3), v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$,

$$\frac{a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3-(b_1v_1+b_2v_2+b_3v_3)k}{\sqrt{(a_1-b_1k)^2+(a_2-b_2k)^2+(a_3-b_3k)^2}}=t$$

Simplifying this gives you a quadratic equation in terms of $k$:

$$(b_1v_1+b_2v_2+b_3v_3-t^2(b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2))k^2\\-(2(a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3)(b_1v_1+b_2v_2+b_3v_3)-t^2(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3))k\\+(a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3)^2-t^2(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)=0$$

It looks complicated, but using computer to calculate the quadratic formula is not that hard.

If there are two roots or one root, it would be the answer. If there are no roots, you can find the maximum or minimum value of the quadratic function. That would be the point that is closest to zero.

Comment: FYI this suffers from the same problem as a naive answer to (-x-1)/sqrt(1+x^2)=1.  You'll conclude that x=0 is an answer, when in fact x = -infinity is the right answer.

Comment: You are right. You might just have to deal with some special cases.